# Need to add custom header according to category ID

Tags: php, wordpress

Need to add custom header according to category ID via `functions.php`.
I set 2 headers pages: `header-19.php` and `header-20.php`.
but nothing happens. what I'm doing wrong?

```
function my_custom_header() {
  if(is_category('19')) {
    get_header('19');
  } elseif(is_category('20')) {
    get_header('20');
  } else {
    get_header();
  }
}
```

Comment: You had a systax error: `else() {`

Comment: @gmc - the syntax is correct, the else is for the code to be executed if all conditions are false

Comment: yes because i've just edited it

Comment: @gmc I appreciate editing for comprehension, but editing the code to correct just makes the question a moot point. Would you mind just answering the question instead?

Comment: I cannot answer the question, I do not know wp well enough. I just pointed out a syntax error in the code, which I am not sure it is the (only) problem here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
function my_custom_header() {
    if (is_category('19')) :
        get_header('19');
    elseif (is_category('20')) :
        get_header('20');
    else :
        get_header();
    endif;
}
```

Then in your page add this

```
<?php my_custom_header(); ?>
```

Comment: tried this code and it is working very well. but wondering if there is an option to add it via a hook in functions.php to save the need to customize the page?

Comment: @James - simple: add `my_custom_header` function in your **functions.php** file, then call it in your page as i mentionned in the response above

Comment: @James - Can you please validate the answer as it answered your primary question, thank you

Comment: I meant without adding this code <?php my_custom_header(); ?> to the page .

Comment: maybe to hook with after_header in the function